# Propagaging Apache rules Automatically for all folders Beneath Root

Tags: apache, htaccess

my webroot folder /httpdocs folder contains a .htaccess file

The first lines look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
# DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php
# ServerSignature Off
```

Now, I want all settings that I have set it to, to be propagated automatically to other folders as well.
How can I do that? Thanks very much for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options directives will be applied to all subdirectories , and can be overridden with .htaccess file in each subdirectory.

mod_rewrite rules thou are not 'propagated' thou